# EXIM не отправляет email на локальные почтовые адреса

Tags: linux, debian, exim4

В корпоративной сети сервер Debian 10 с EXIM отправляет письма с помощью php mail().
На всякие внешние почтовые адреса (@yandex.ru, @google.com, @mail.ru и др.) все отлично доходит, на корпоративную почту - нет.

EXIM при отправке получает адрес почтового сервера через MX-записи локального DNS-сервера, среди которых нет одной записи, предназначенной для внешней почты, а для у имеющихся MX-записей доменов закрыт 25 порт.

Общение с сисадминами привело к единственному возможному варианту решения проблемы - настроить EXIM так, чтобы все письма, отправляемые на корпоративные адреса почты (несколько доменов) или вообще все-все письма отправлялись на промежуточный сервер с IP-адресом 192.168.1.2 (например).

Подскажите, как это сделать (в таком-то файле **/etc/exim4/conf.d/** изменить или добавить то-то)
Гугл не помог, что-то я находил про smarthost, пробовал, но не проблема не была решена.

Comment: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.00/doc/html/spec_26.html, самый последний пример. Возможно, придётся изучить принципы конфигурирования и отладки конфигурации exim чуть глубже, чем "что-то я находил".

Comment: Дополнение к вопросу: оказывается Smarthost не включен для EXIM, соответственно, все его правила не работают.
Выясняю, как его включить без переустановки EXIM, если это не возможно - буду переустанавливать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все оказалось просто - нужно запустить команду в консоли:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

и выполнить конфигурирование EXIM:

- включить SMARTHOST и указать промежуточный сервер (домен или IP)

Теперь все работает!

Comment: При конфигурировании идут последовательные страницы с описанием и выбора настроек, на некоторых имеются поля для ввода текста. Все просто и интуитивно понятно.